# JSX expressions must have one parent element.ts(2657)

Tags: javascript, java, reactjs, react-native

i am using React Native, i am freshman there , what is the problem here: mistake is there
i am using React Native, i am freshman there , what is the problem here: mistake is there
i am using React Native, i am freshman there , what is the problem here: mistake is there
i am using React Native, i am freshman there , what is the problem here: mistake is there
i am using React Native, i am freshman there , what is the problem here: mistake is there
i am using React Native, i am freshman there , what is the problem here: mistake is there

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';

export default function App() {
  return (
  


    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text>Open up App.js to start working on your app!</Text>
      <StatusBar style="auto" />
    </View>

    <View >
<Text>ffff</Text>
      </View>
 
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    backgroundColor: 'red',
  },
});
```

Comment: What's the problem you're facing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've to wrap up your content in a parent section or view like this:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, StatusBar } from 'react-native';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <StatusBar barStyle="dark-content"/>
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text>Open up App.js to start working on your app!</Text>
      </View>

      <View >
        <Text>ffff</Text>
      </View>
    </>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    backgroundColor: 'red',
  },
});
```